# Trying to parse out vCard name entry with Regex

Tags: .net, regex, vcf-vcard

I have the following Regex to parse out a vCard: (VB)

```
        Dim options As New RegexOptions()
        options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
        regex = New Regex("(?<strElement>(N)) (;[^:]*)? (;CHARSET=UTF-8)? (:(?<strSurname>([^;\n\r]*))) (;(?<strGivenName>([^;\n\r]*)))? (;(?<strMidName>([^;\n\r]*)))? (;(?<strPrefix>([^;\n\r]*)))? (;(?<strSuffix>[^;\n\r]*))?", options)
        m = regex.Match(s)
        If m.Success Then
            Surname = m.Groups("strSurname").Value
            GivenName = m.Groups("strGivenName").Value
            MiddleName = m.Groups("strMidName").Value
            Prefix = m.Groups("strPrefix").Value
            Suffix = m.Groups("strSuffix").Value
        End If
```

It works when I have a vCard like:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Bacon;Kevin;Francis;Mr.;Jr.
FN: Mr. Kevin Francis Bacon Jr.
ORG:Movies.com
```

But it doesn't work correctly when the vCard is like this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:Bacon;Kevin
FN:Kevin Bacon
ORG:Movies.com
```

The regex assigns the <strSuffix> to Kevin, and not <strGivenName> like I wanted.  How can I fix this?

Adapted regex came from here: [vCard regex](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/syncmldotnet/wiki/vCard)

Comment: Also, I wonder how this can even work on the first example input. Why wouldn't it match `N:VCARD`? Or `N:2.1`? Or `N: Mr. Kevin Francis Bacon Jr.`? (Well, actually only the first two are odd, since you only return the first match)

Comment: Another one: why do you want `Bacon` to be assigned to `<strGivenName>`? Did you mean `Kevin`? Did you mean `<strSurname>`?

Comment: I added the RegexOptions to my original question, and I did mean Kevin as the <strGivenName>.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: IgnorePATTERNwhitepace is only for pattern commenting and not for the regex process. There are no comments in your pattern, nor does it span multiple lines; hence remove that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be good with regex pattern

```
^N(?:;(?!CHARSET=UTF-8)[^:]*|)(?:;CHARSET=UTF-8|):(?<strSurname>[^;\n\r]*);?(?<strGivenName>[^;\n\r]*);?(?<strMidName>[^;\n\r]*);?(?<strPrefix>[^;\n\r]*);?(?<strSuffix>[^;\n\r]*)
```

See **[this](http://ideone.com/m1thJq)** example and **[this](http://ideone.com/l4HETA)** example.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid parsing each line with a unique regex,  but instead tokenize each line. Then have the resulting process determine if there are missing (optional) items. Here is a pattern which simply tokenizes each line by its code and data items (*use explicit capture & multiline*).

```
^(?<Code>[^:]+)(:)((?<Tokens>[^;\r\n]+)(;?))+
```

That puts the emphasis on creating individual code objects which handle the business logic of whether data is missing or not. Failures are no longer regex failures, but business logic post processing failures which IMHO are better to debug and maintain.