# Regular Expression to pick out values from vcard

Tags: c#, regex, vcf-vcard

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//iOS 5.1//EN
N:Tom;First ;Mid;Pre;Suffg
FN:Pre First Mid Tom Suffg
NICKNAME:Nick
X-PHONETIC-FIRST-NAME:Fn
X-PHONETIC-LAST-NAME:Ln
ORG:The Organization;
TITLE:VP Investor Relations
TEL;type=WORK;type=VOICE;type=pref:003-000-11111
item1.ADR;type=WORK;type=pref:;;;test;VA;12345;
BDAY;value=date:1992-03-27
item2.X-ABDATE;type=pref:2014-03-27
item2.X-ABLabel:_$!<Anniversary>!$_
item3.X-ABDATE:2013-03-27
item3.X-ABLabel:_$!<Other>!$_
NOTE:Test note
REV:2014-03-27T10:25:11Z
UID:2DCC7DC1-04F4-4A1E-A268-80E346F610AD
END:VCARD
```

I need to know the regular expressions to pick out the date values (birthday, anniversary, Other).

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Eidt: i just asked to pick out the date values i am able to pick other values. The link given is not helpful for me.**

Comment: What has been your attempt?

Comment: It seems that his has been asked and answered already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420851/trying-to-parse-out-vcard-name-entry-with-regex - I suggest you implement your birthdate parsing in a similar manner and if you get stuck, **specify** your difficulties in another question

Comment: how did googling "Regex for Dates" not help you?

Comment: @Jerry : i tried this to pick Birthday date but no luck     regex = new Regex(@"(?<strElement>(BDAY))   (:(?<strBDAY>([^\n\r]*)))", options);

Comment: @Syeda I added an answer saying what was wrong with that regex. You weren't so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you had was quite close, but a few changes are required:

```
(?<strElement>(BDAY)) (:(?<strBDAY>([^\n\r]*)))
              ^    ^  ^            ^        ^ ^
```

The parts I pointed out above are the either unnecessary (in case of parentheses) or causing a problem.

Change the space to something like `\S+` perhaps and remove the extra parens:

```
(?<strElement>BDAY)\S+:(?<strBDAY>[^\n\r]*)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/bY1tH6)

Answer (score 0):

Without DataTime validation:

```
\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}
```